# CellPainting in DataGridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

There is a filled DataGridView. There is a CellPainting event

```vb
  Private Sub DataGridView1_CellPainting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellPainting
        If e.RowIndex Mod 2 = 1 Then
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightBlue
            e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Navy
        Else
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.White
            e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Navy
        End If
    End Sub
```

There is also a text field. By which data is selected in the DataGridView by hiding rows:

```vb
  Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
          For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            If row.Cells(0).Value.ToString.ToLower.Contains(TextBox1.Text.ToLower) Then
                row.Visible = True
            Else
                row.Visible = False
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

But when there is a selection by writing to the Datagridview, CellPainting Processes is not correct.

Comment: You need to clarify what “correct” IS. Describing the problem as _”not correct”_ tells us nothing about what IS correct or what IS not correct. Just guessing… are you aware that the grids `CellPainting` event will obviously NOT fire for cells that are “hidden.” In addition, “hiding” a grids row does NOT change any of the existing row indexes… the row is still there… it is just not displayed because the `CellPainting` event is not firing for the hidden cells.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. Could you tell me what to do in this situation? that the lines would still be painted through one?

Comment: Are you simply trying to alternate the colors of the rows? The grid has an Alternating rows property; however, I do not think it will stay maintained if the code programmatically “hides” a row. But I can post a simple solution to color the rows with alternating colors. You could call it after hiding the rows.

Comment: Thanks. If it's not difficult, post the solution.

Comment: Before I post an answer, does the grid use a data source? Is what I am getting at… is that if the grid has a data source, then instead of making rows in the grid “visible/hidden”… that you “filter” the grids data source. This should be easier than your current approach AND THEN you COULD use the grids `AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle` property and eliminate all this all together. In other words, set the grids alternating row property, dump the grids `CellPainting` event… Then… in the text box `TextChanged` event, “filter” the grids data source. That is all you need; the grid will do the rest.

Comment: There is no data source binding in the DataGridView. The DatagridView is populated with just code.  DataGridView1.Rows.Add(TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text, TextBox4.Text)

Answer (score 1):

If the grid *”is populated with just code”* … then great… “make” a data source and fill “IT” instead of the grid. Then you “will” have a data source. I highly recommend you use a data source for the grid. It will make things much easier for you in numerous ways. A `BindingSource/BindingList` and a `DataGridView` play nicely together and usually make things much easier.

However a brute force approach may go something like…

```
Private Sub ColorAlternateRowsInGrid()
  Dim curIndex = 0
  For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    If Not row.IsNewRow Then
      If (row.Visible) Then
        If curIndex Mod 2 = 1 Then
          row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightBlue
          row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Navy
        Else
          row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White
          row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Navy
        End If
        curIndex = curIndex + 1
      End If
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

***An easier approach using a `BindingSource` and `DataTable`***

If we set the grids `AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle` property and use a data source for the grid. Then all we need to do is “filter” the grids data source from the text box.

Example, using two global variables a `DataTable` named `GridTable` that we will get from the code instead of filling the grid manually. Then a `BindingSource` named `GridBS` to make filtering a little easier…

```
Dim GridTable As DataTable
Dim GridBS As BindingSource
```

Then in the forms `Load` event we will initialize these global variables…

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  GridTable = GetData() ‘ <- GetData is a method supplied by you to return the data in a `DataTable`
  GridBS = New BindingSource()
  GridBS.DataSource = GridTable
  DataGridView1.DataSource = GridBS
  DataGridView1.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightBlue
  DataGridView1.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Navy
End Sub
```

Then to filter the grid when the user types text into the text box, may look something like…

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
  GridBS.Filter = "ColName LIKE '*" + TextBox1.Text + "*'"
End Sub
```

Note we do not have to reset the grids data source… the `BindingSource` takes care of most of this automatically.

I hope this makes sense.